# Creating line from center point, angle and length in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, expression, polyline-creation, geometry-generator

How can I generate a line with given center point, angle and length in QGIS?

I am analyzing that auto extraction lineament for geologic structure analyze.

Comment: `y=mx+c` should be all you need

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 4):

Creating a line without PyQGIS, using only QGIS expressions: Use either [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) (for visualization only) or create actual geomtries with [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) - use this one to create actual geometries (real lines): [see here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392618/use-qgis-expressions-to-create-geometries-difference-between-geometry-generator/392619#392619)).

If the point should be in the middle of the line, simply extend the line. Use this expression for a line with length of 20 and angle (*azimuth:* angle clockwise from north) of 112° degrees:

```
extend (
    make_line(
        $geometry,
        project(
            $geometry,
            20,
            radians(112)
        )
    ),
    20,
    0
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I really want to know is create real lines (features). The method you taught me is just styling. And the position of the line is the center point of the point. Again, please answer my question.