# Creating line from center of points, and define angle using azimuth stored in the attribute table

Tags: qgis, geometry, expression, geometry-generator, qgis-expression

Similar to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415812/creating-line-from-center-point-angle-and-length-in-qgis) I would like to create lines on points in a point layer. The attribute table of the points layer includes a column named `azimuth` which contains the azimuth/direction these points are directed to. Using the following expression in the Geometry by Expression tool, I know I can create a line with length of 20 and angle (azimuth: angle clockwise from north) of 112° degrees:

```
extend (
    make_line(
        $geometry,
        project(
            $geometry,
            20,
            radians(112)
        )
    ),
    20,
    0
)
```

How can I use the azimuth values (of type Integer64) stored in the `azimuth` column to set the angle of the lines independently? I tried to substitute `112` with `$azimuth` in the example, but without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$azimuth` suggests you're accessing a property of the current feature - but `$azimuth` is not defined.

Also, I don't see why you've added `extend()` to the whole expression.

`make_line($geometry,project($geometry,20,radians(azimuth)))` works just fine.